# D Link DSL G624T Router will work wirelessly but not via cable

Tags: ethernet

I have a D Link router which works in providing a wireless internet connection for my main PC and secondary notebook.

I have been advised that the internet connection to the main pc will be better if I wire the router directly to the PC.

I have tried this and can not get a connection.

I just keep getting the message network cable unplugged.

I have had the ethernet adaptor checked out on the pc and the cable is good ( also checked out).

Anything I can do or do I have a bad router.

I have tried the cable in all 4 ports and the message is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a failure on the LAN ports. On my 8 years old G624T after an hipcup I noticed a progressive decay of the LAN and at some point I was able to connect only through the wifi (indeed quite useful if you need a small private network, not connected to Internet).

I could be a switch failure caused by electrolytic capacitors, but there is a solution, it seems:

- [DSLG624T: ethernet problems](http://www.routertech.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=5622)
- [How to fix D-Link G624T ethernet ports @ 10 Mbps only](http://www.routertech.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=4662)

Answer (score 0):

> I just keep getting the message network cable unplugged.

Sometimes I have to disable the wired network adapter and re-enable it after switching from wireless to wired connection on my Laptop.

There is another simple check: Put **both** ends of your cable into the Router - using 2 LAN Ports. Then look at the front LEDs. If they light up, your cable seems in order, if not then most likely your cable is not OK. Try a different one.

Note that ISBN uses RJ-45 connectors too (at least here in Europe), but while ISDN will work over LAN (CAT 5 or better) cables, Ethernet will not work over ISDN cables - which have only 4 wires.

Comment: Thanks but I've had the cable checked out at a shop and it's definately ok.